# Magento 2.4 Products are not showing in category - Elastic Search enabled

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, elasticsearch

I have recently installed a Magento 2.4 for a client, configured elastic search and everything worked well until I created a few additional store views (my assumption).

Now the products are visible everywhere, on the home page, in search results, by direct URLs but not in the categories.

Any clue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, it was a custom attribute created by an extension.

**The problem** - attribute type was `text` and it was set to use in Layered Navigation.

**The fix** - tracked that attribute in `catalog_eav_attribute` table and set the column `is_filterable` to 0 (you won't be able to change this from the backend as the field is enabled for editing only for catalog input type Yes/No, Dropdown, Multiple Select and Price)

The problem occurs only when you have Elastic Search enabled.

The best way to identify the attribute is to execute the below SQL query -

```
select * from catalog_eav_attribute EAV1 join eav_attribute EAV2 on EAV2.attribute_id = EAV1.attribute_id and frontend_input = 'text' where EAV1.is_filterable = 1
```